# Compiling a debug version without opening the debug perspective?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, fdt

I've migrated to FDT from flashdevelop and kind of have a hard time getting things to work the way I'm used to. In Flashdevelop, you could easily choose if the compiled swf was a release or debug version. In FDT however, it seems like there is no way to compile a version that has debugging information without it automatically opening up the debug perspective with a ton of debug windows, a profiler and actually entering debug mode. 
As an extra plus, I keep getting a message saying "This feature is only available in FDT Max", although from what I know the debugger is included in the free version.
Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do or should I just get used to this new way of working?

Answer (score 1):

Francis is right. `Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives` is the correct place to set this. You have to adjust the setting of *Open the associated perspective when an application suspend*

[image: perspective switch settings dialog]

Alternatively you can use the perspective switch dialog that comes up when your application hits a breakpoint, check *Remember my decision* and close the dialog with 'No'.

Answer (score 0):

Look at (from the top menu bar) `Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives` This should allow you to choose what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering :)   


I've actually tried that already and set the "Debug" perspective to None/Flast FDT. Both of these did not seem to work - it's as if the setting is ignore and the Debug perspective opens anyway.

Comment: I wonder then if this might be a bug in the FDT stuff; that they are ignoring these preferences. I would encourage you to file a bug with them.